# Minimum heap - DecreaseKey function

Tags: heap

Here are two different implementations of the function `DecreaseKey` for a Minimum-Heap structure.

`DecreaseKey` gets the minimum-heap array, the index of a node in that heap, and the new value to be assigned to that node. It is assumed that the new value is not greater than the node's current value. The heap property is restored if necessary.

```
DecreaseKey(A, i, val) -
    While (i > 1 and A[parent(i)] > val):
       A[i] = A[parent(i)]
       i = parent(i)
    A[i] = val
```

```
DecreaseKey(A, i, val) -
    A[i] = val
    While (i > 1 and A[parent(i)] > A[i]):
       Swap(&A[i], &A[parent(i)])
       i = parent(i)
```

My question is - are these algorithms equivalent? Or is one of them logically wrong?

Is the result of both of them the same for every given input and every given minimum-heap?

Comment: Posting images of code is not really welcomed here.

Answer (score 0):

Both are equivalent, while the first will run faster in general.

While the second version will move `val` from the child to the parent slot in each iteration, the second version will wait with moving `val` until it is clear which its final spot is, and will only then store it there.